# Inheriting from a template class using the inheriting class with C++20 concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm trying to write a Singleton base class similar to Ogre3Ds [`Ogre::Singleton`](https://github.com/ehsan/ogre/blob/master/OgreMain/include/OgreSingleton.h) using C++20's `std::default_initializable`.

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template <std::default_initializable T>
struct Singleton {};

class Foo: public Singleton<Foo> {};
```

This code does not compile:

```
error C7602: 'Singleton': the associated constraints are not satisfied
```

Would I expect it to? If not: Why?

I'm using the latest MSVC with `/std:c++latest`.

Comment: [GCC 11.0.0 HEAD](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0Zj4Q2ef9dmIOC5x) doesn't seem to like it either, more or less the same reason.  I hope an answer explains this and also whether it is something specific to `std::default_initializable` or happens more generally to (certain kinds of) concepts with CRTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Compiling this with GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/e4c7Eh) gives a more helpful error message:

> ```
> ...
> /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/type_traits:895:52:
> error: static assertion failed: template argument must be a complete
> class or an unbounded array
> 895 |       static_assert(std::__is_complete_or_unbounded(__type_identity<_Tp>{}),
>     |                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

In particular, at the point of declaring `Singleton<Foo>`, `Foo` is not yet a complete type: the class body has not opened yet. As such there is no way for the compiler to know at that point whether or not the concept can truly be satisfied.

You can see a similar issue with the use of static assertions; consider, for example, the following (which also fails to compile for much the same reason):

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Singleton {
    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_destructible_v<T>);
};

class Foo: public Singleton<Foo> {};
```

---

If you wish to enforce the constraint regardless, you can still use concepts: you just need to use it in a location where the type will be a complete type. For example, you might `static_assert` that the concept holds in the destructor:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Singleton {
    ~Singleton() {
        static_assert(std::default_initializable<T>);
    }
};

struct Foo : Singleton<Foo> {};             // compiles
struct Bar : Singleton<Bar> { Bar(int); };  // doesn't compile (when used)
```

[(Live)](https://godbolt.org/z/xhheof)

Comment: So it sounds like concepts and CRTP don't mix?  I.e., you can't constraint a CRTP type parameter via a concept.  Because all (nearly all?) concepts would require a complete type to be able to validate it is satisfied?

Comment: @davidbak as far as I'm aware, yes. That said, you can use the same tricks for doing dependent static assertions on the type; e.g., using `static_assert(std::default_initializable<T>)` in the destructor, and so forth.

Comment: @davidbak updated with an example of how you can still "constrain" the type regardless, though it's not as nice.

Comment: Thanks for that update!  It isn't as nice a syntax, yes, but it gives you the guarantee that the CRTP type parameter meets the contract _and provides documentation_ without having to read the code ... always a weakness with CRTP ... (which otherwise is an _excellent_ pattern for mixins ...)

Answer (score 5):

The reason why you can't do this is because at the point where Foo is given as a template parameter to Singleton, it is an incomplete type, and an [incomplete type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type) is not initializable at all (so it can not be default-initialized)

Here is a sample program that give a way more understandable error:

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    T value{};
};

struct B : A<B>{};
```

Compiler error (GCC 10.2)

```
<source>:5:7: error: 'A<T>::value' has incomplete type
    5 |     T value{};
      |       ^~~~~
<source>:8:8: note: forward declaration of 'struct B'
    8 | struct B : A<B>
      |        ^
```